# How do I detect when input value changes real-time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get my input field element to remove a class immediately after the input value changes. Currently, I'm able to detect the changes and remove the class 'invalid', but only after the input field is inactive. Here's my code;

```
fieldsArr.forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('change', function() {
                this.classList.remove('invalid');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Instead of listening for `change`, listen for `input`

Comment: "Javascript" and "real-time" don't really belong in a sentence together....

Comment: @JaredSmith what do you mean by that? JavaScript allows real-time updates in many cases, for example - this website, by using WebSockets.

Comment: @Jared JavaScript is one of too few languages that is absolutely real-time it uses the so called JIT-compiler, which means not only does it operate in real-time with the code supplied but also with the code it has generated and and when it comes to events, all emitters  are real-time and so are the freaking event handlers. 
JavaScript's original name was **Live Script**, for a reason!

Comment: @BekimBacaj oh I'm well aware. But that's not real time: Javascript (like every other garbage collected language) has GC pauses at unpredictable times. Not to mention the event loop. You and I have **very** different definitions of "real time". FWIW I use the [one from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing). I'm not saying Javascript is a bad/inferior language, it just makes different trade-offs. Don't take this stuff so personally.

Comment: @DaCurse see my response above.

Comment: @JaredSmith So you're basically nitpicking and referring to a very specific detail, sure bud.

Comment: @DaCurse I'm not nitpicking at all: I'm pointing out that the term "real time" has an agreed-upon technical meaning, one that doesn't apply here. That's not a "very specific detail", it's what real-time computing *is*. If someone uses "parse" to talk about simply reading a file, that doesn't make it correct usage because they thought that's what the word means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `input` event instead, as the name suggests it would fire each time an input is made, see this example on how to use the event:

```js
let inputElem = document.querySelector('input');

inputElem.addEventListener('input', () => {
  console.log(inputElem.value); // Log the new value after an input is made
});
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know 'input' is a type of event listener though. I tried it and it works flawlessly. Thanks so much :)

Comment: It's really neat, but still has some experimental features.

Comment: Nothing experimental here, it's been part of the specs for a long time. Even IE9 (9 years old) [supports it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event)

Comment: I wasn't talking about the event itself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/dataTransfer

Answer (score -2):

If you want to listen for events, your elemet should be extended from EventEmitter.

Comment: DOM Elements implement `EventTarget`, which lets you listen to events, by using `addEventListener`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget